# Map is not full screen in Google Earth Pro

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics, google-earth

I have installed Google Earth Pro 7.3.0.3830 (64-bit) on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I launch Google Earth Pro, map is shown in very small window. I have un-installed and re-installed but the problem is as it is.[image: map is on left upper corner]

Comment: Try [Marble](https://marble.kde.org/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Happened to me too, Its a graphics driver problem. It does not work on X.org nouveau graphics driver. More on it [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/IHTPNCzW4EA;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/category$3Aissues-and-troubleshooting). So you can uninstall the present version 7.3 and install 7.1 version from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0YZ3Xi3rgTcTNjelJwUEVkNDQ/view).

Comment: The proper solution is to use the Nvidia proprietary drivers which is now a requirement. Downgrading is not recommended, regardless of what has been discussed in the link you posted. It's just procrastination. At one point, sooner than later, the old version will stop working.

Comment: @Deepank Thank you. It has solved the issue for now. I have downgraded the version.

Comment: MichaelBay, Thank you for your input, I have tried many things to update my graphics driver (RS690 Radeon X1200), but found that open source gallium is most reliable.

Comment: I have a Macbook Air with some intel graphics card that had the same issue. Using 7.1.x made it work here, too.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the latest Intel Graphics drivers on 16.0.4 LTS and doesn't work; downgrading does.  Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5916 bus-ID: 00:02.0;  Display Server: X.Org 1.19.5 driver: intel;  Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz;  GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2); GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.1 - padoka PPA Direct Rendering: Yes

Comment: Excellent. I really don't like using the nvidia driver if I can avoid it and it seems I can. They're always forcing us to use what we don't like, fortunately some users are out there sharing info on how not to be forced into their desires :D
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I have *nouveau* graphics driver and *Google Earth Pro 7.3.2.5776 (64-bit)* on *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*.

You can try to use `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE` environment variable like this:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 /opt/google/earth/pro/googleearth
```

But this is just for a little look, because it is terribly slow.

Comment: Only thing that seems to work on my newish Intel GPU laptop.... and I can't tell it's sofware, it's pretty fast!

Answer (score 0):

It got this problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I have a NVidia Graphic Card. 
I solved the issue like this.

To update the NVidia driver, execute in a terminal :

**$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall**

After, reboot.
It worked for me.